# Как удалить из массива числа в которых есть 5?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, mobile

Подскажите пожалуйста как удалить из массива те числа в которых есть цифра 5?

let array = [5, 3, 20, 15, 12, 35, 105, 45]

Comment: Пройтись по массиву и проверить if (element == 5 || element % 10 = 5) { ... }

Comment: @Vanya228 числа типа 51, 100500: добрый день :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
array.filter {!String($0).contains("5")}
```

Comment: Точно. Я, то думаю, почему у меня не работает. Надо было привести к String. 
Спасибо, Олег!

Comment: Пожалуйста, you are welcome)